# How to set margin for different element present in a same container - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

The elements are nested like this.

```
<div class = "root">
 <div class = "mask"></div>
 <div class = "a"></div>
 <div class = "b"></div>
 <div class = "c"></div>
</div>`
```

Is it possible to set a specific margin only for the `mask` div?

For example, if the root width is 300px, can I have a shorter width than that for the mask div?

[Shimmer is over lapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isvLn.png)

Inside the mask row there is a table which contains the shimmer div and the width of the shimmer which caused it to overlap over the scrollbar. Is it possible to correct this issue?

Comment: Hi, can you share your css?

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand exactly what you want, but here are some tips:
you can set overflow hidden on .root div, so overflow will be hidden and display:flex, so if

```
.root{
overflow: hidden;
display:flex;
}
```

if a child element of .mask is overflowing it, do same on .mask. if you want clearer answer, ask clearer question.

Comment: HI sorry for that root container contains both shimmer and scrollbar, so my problem is shimmer overlaps the scrollbar is there any way that the over lapsed part can be hidden or make it go under the scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

```css
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

add this style

Comment: in which div i need to add this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just try this i hope it helps

```
.mask{
overflow:hidden;
//now giv here margin left according to your need or just give margin
}
```